# Reading the contacts (name and phone number) and listing them

Tags: android, listview, contacts

I added three contacts to my list of contacts. Then I wanted to show (list) them using a cursor and a ListAdapter. I don't get any error but instead of the list of contacts I see written on the screen only the following URI:

content://com.android.contacts/phone_lookup

What does it mean? I might show you the code too, but I'm not sure it is necessary.

Thanks for help!

Edit by ninetwozero (inlined the code):

```
protected void showContacts() { 
    String [] projection = new String[] { StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER }; 
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.txtName, R.id.txtNumber }; 

    txt.setText(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI.toString()); 
    //Uri contacts = Data.CONTENT_URI; 
    Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null); 
    startManagingCursor(managedCursor);
    ListAdapter sca=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.list_entry,managedCursor,projection,to); 
    list.setAdapter(sca); 
}
```

Comment: You should probably show some code. :-)

Comment: protected void showContacts() {
String [] projection=new String[] {  
    StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
    Phone.NUMBER,
    };
  int[] to = new int[] { R.id.txtName, R.id.txtNumber, };
txt.setText(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI.toString());
  //Uri contacts = Data.CONTENT_URI;
  Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null); 
  startManagingCursor(managedCursor);

  ListAdapter sca=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.list_entry,managedCursor,projection,to);
  list.setAdapter(sca);

 }

Comment: Here's the method used to list the name and the phone number of each contact.

Comment: I added the code to your original post. :-)

Comment: Thank you for adding the code to the original message!

Comment: I discovered which is the line that writes that output on the screen phone: it is the one starting with txt.setText(...
Ok, so this in fact answers my question and leaves me working on the program to get the list of contacts.... hopefully.